# how to avoid duplicate filename in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

As we all know wordpress stores your uploaded files (for me,it's just JPG files) in a folder named "uploads" under "wp-content". Files are separated into folders based on year and month.

Now i want to copy every file from every folder into a single folder on another server (for some purposes). I want to know, does wordpress rename duplicate files? is it possible that my files be overwritten on the new server?

If yes, how can i avoid this? is there a way to make wordpress rename files before storing them?

Answer (score 0):

You can scan your uploaded file folder and you have to options:
1.- Set a random name for each file
2.- Set a name convention including path and file name, for example: my_path_my_filename.jpg


By the way your file wont be overwritten cause is another server

Answer (score 0):

This question seems about export/import...

Check [exported XML](https://codex.wordpress.org/Manage_Export_SubPanel) ([WordPress eXtended RSS file format](https://devtidbits.com/2011/03/16/the-wordpress-extended-rss-wxr-exportimport-xml-document-format-decoded-and-explained/)), you can download all media URLs at `<wp:attachment_url>` tag... Use any XML parser.

Example without parser, at terminal:

```
  cat exportedSite.xml | grep wp:attachment_url
```

will list all URLs. Each parsed URL can be downloaded by `curl` or `wget`.

If you whant to restore the XML backup, change (only) the URLs of the `wp:attachment_url` tags by the new repo URLs